# PyQt receive POST request to GUI

Tags: python, flask, pyqt5

I tried to receive a POST request into PyQT5 GUI, but I don't understand how to do this)

As I understood from books and other sources, I need to run the server in a separate thread and the interface itself in another thread and transmit what will arrive in the post request via signals. But something is not working out for me. I chose a Flask as a server, it seemed to be the simplest solution, the server starts, but accepts requests, but does not transmit to GUI.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from flask import Flask, request


class ServerThred(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    http_server = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.http_server.run(port=5000)
        self.mysignal.emit(str('Server Start'))

    @http_server.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def result(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.form)
        self.mysignal.emit('received')
        return request.form


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(500,300)
        self.text_line = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.text_line.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.text_line.setStyleSheet('color: black;')
        self.text_line.setText('RUN')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.text_line)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.server_thread = ServerThred()
        self.server_thread.start()
        self.server_thread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.text_line.setText(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
Error: site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
TypeError: result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?!? `self = ServerThred()` remove that line, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, it is mistake. Thanks. This resolve my problem?

Comment: if not set self,   self.mysignal.emit('received')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: if i set self in method - return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
TypeError: result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Thanks, add error message and clean unused parts of code.